# AppleScript Can't Get Argument Value Through Terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal, arguments, applescript

I'm working on a Java GUI and I'm trying to make a button that can start a FaceTime call with a given phone number. Here is an oversimplified version of the java code.

```
String cellNum = "18001234567";
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Users/faris/Desktop/call.app --args " + cellNum);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After researching how do to this, I copied part of an AppleScript app I found online that I named call.app and modified it so it takes in an input argument phone number rather than manually entering it into the script. I've run the program with an actual phone number entered instead of the input variable and it works fine so I know that the problem lies with passing the argument.

**call.app**

```
on run args
    set input to first item of args
    open location "tel://" & input & "?audio=yes"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 36
    end tell
end run
```

This is the error I get every time from the AppleScript.

```
Can’t get item 1. (-1728)
```

I've never used AppleScript before so I'm completely lost currently. Haven't found anything similar anywhere on SO. Any advice would be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Cause:

`Error -1728` in AppleScript is `"Can't get «script»"`, indicating that the `first item of args` is a script object reference.  This means that the command-line argument is not getting passed to your AppleScript's `run` handler.

#### Solution:

Instead of saving your AppleScript as an applet, save it (export it) as either a `.scpt` or an `.applescript` file.  Then substitute your `exec(...)` Java command for this:

```
exec("osascript /path/to/applescript " + cellNum);
```